# jQuery not allowing to add a child

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addLftTab">
            Add Left Tab
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addrghtTab">
            Add Right Tab
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Passage1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```jquery
$("#addLftTab").on("click", function() {
    $("#tablist > li:first").prepend('<li><a href="#">Passage</a></li>');
});
$("#addrghtTab").on("click", function() {
    $("#tablist > li:last").append('<li><a href="#">Passage</a></li>');
});
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? I am noob in this css child section. I tried but unable to find what is making not work. using bootstrap, jquery plugin 1.8.

Comment: Is that your code verbatim?

Comment: Put your script in a <script> tag

Comment: You dont have a node with id `tablist` . Did you forget to add it to the `ul` element ?

Comment: Thanks bro. I gave my importance on the code. Then looking into the html id=tablist but I saw there was role. Such a stupid thing. I tried most code. I was confused on the code. Since, it doesn't showed me any error. I was confused. Whether my code is wrong. Thanks bro. I made it short, but actually I have added the script tag. Anyways Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to set an id (*`id="tablist"`*) to the `ul` element (*as that is what `$('#tablist')` looks for*)
2. then you must append/prepend to that and not the `li` elements.

```js
$("#addLftTab").on("click", function () {
    $("#tablist").prepend('<li><a href="#">Passage</a></li>');
});

$("#addrghtTab").on("click", function () {
    $("#tablist").append('<li><a href="#">Passage</a></li>');
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addLftTab">Add Left Tab</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addrghtTab">Add Right Tab</button>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tablist">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Passage1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID in UL tag is missing, it should be:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tablist">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Passage1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an ID on your `<ul>`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tablist" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
<a href="#">Passage1</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I've created a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/4e084p1g/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like below:

```
$('[role="tablist"] > li:first')//since you used role attribute
```

If you want your jquery code to be the same then just assign the id to that element.